# How to delete previous zero rows with the same id when the first condition is met in Pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataset, I need to delete the previous 0 rows if flag is 1.

```
ID      Flag
103200  0
103200  1
103200  0
104752  0
104752  0
104752  1
104752  0
104752  1
104752  0
104752  0
104760  0
104760  1
```

Here is the result I want:

```
ID     Flag
103200  1
103200  0
104752  1
104752  0
104752  1
104752  0
104752  0
104760  1
```

Comment: the rule depends on column `ID` as well. Why is the 4th record still in the desired result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [`groupby.cummax`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.cummax.html) and [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
out = df[df.groupby('ID')['Flag'].cummax().ne(0)]

# or
# out = df[df['Flag'].ne(0).groupby(df['ID']).cummax()]
```

output:

```
        ID  Flag
1   103200     1
2   103200     0
5   104752     1
6   104752     0
7   104752     1
8   104752     0
9   104752     0
11  104760     1
```

Answer (score 0):

use the dataframe index to get the index where flag==1 the drop row using the index minus 1.

```
data="""ID      Flag
103200  0
103200  1
103200  0
104752  0
104752  0
104752  1
104752  0
104752  1
104752  0
104752  0
104760  0
104760  1"""

mylist=[]
data = data.split("\n")
for item in data:
    elements=item.split('      ')
    if len(elements) == 1:
        elements=item.split('  ')
    mylist.append(elements)

df = pd.DataFrame(mylist)
df.columns = df.iloc[0]
df.drop(index=df.index[0], 
        axis=0, 
        inplace=True)
df["Flag"] = df["Flag"].astype(int)
df.drop(df[df["Flag"] == 1].index - 1, inplace=True)
print(df)
```

output

```
0       ID  Flag
2   103200     1
3   103200     0
4   104752     0
6   104752     1
8   104752     1
9   104752     0
10  104752     0
12  104760     1
```